# convert relative urls to absolute urls when extracting links out of a html file

Tags: java, url, apache-tika

After fetching a webpage i want to extract all outlinks of that html page in absolute form. Html pages usually have relative urls (i'm extracting these by Apache Tika) in the following forms:

```
    link.html
    ./link.html
    somehost/link.html
    /path/link.html
    ./path/link.html
```

I want to convert all these to absolute urls.
Is there any consistent Java library to perform this so that i don't have to use if else for these? because there may be many other forms that i'm not aware and i need to have something that works with any kind of outlinks specially the ones mentioned here.

Comment: Check [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I need a method like public URL getAbsolute(URL parent, String relativeURL). Using URI class i need to know the protocol, path, scheme, host, etc. and for knowing all those i need to use if else on my relative URL. But i should go and check all the functionalities that URI class provides. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you would need them in order to create an **absolute** URL...